# QuickFIXJ FieldnotFound exception

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

In my application I am receiving a huge FIX messages. Should I check the tag is present for all the tags I retrieving. If I am not checking the presence of a tag, I get FieldNotFound exception in case the tag is not exist in the message. Is there way to bypass the isSetField(Field) method for checking for the tag is present in the message. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Bibin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should switch on message validation within your [quickfix/j settings](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/usermanual/1.5.0/usage/configuration.html)

This will mean that you no longer need to do an explicit isSet check on any tag that is deemed mandatory, as any message missing such a tag would be rejected.

Once you've done this, you would still need to do an isSet for tags that are optional in your messages.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the FIX data dictionary documentation : http://www.quickfixn.org/tutorial/custom-fields-groups-and-messages